Why does the fluid simulation suddenly accelerate/explode when following a guide?
This is my first time dealing with fluids and physics in Blender, so I can't even begin to comprehend what's happening here. But the gist of the problem is that the fluid "particles" (if they can be called that) suddenly gain speed and move erratically. This didn't happen until I added a Bezier curve to serve as a guide for the fluid. To better understand the issue please check this video.

Here are my domain's settings:




Flow settings:


Guide settings:

